# Enabling the URL of a folder connected via symlink

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, symbolic-link, symlink

**Scenario Description:**

In my workplace we have a `DomainController` and use `TerminalServices`.
There are different types of servers running on the DC (e.g. `webapi` , `app`). The dev guys developing the API want to access a folder (i.e. `app\images`) through a URL directing to `webapi`. So I thought I could achieve this with symlinks.

I created a symlink at `\\DC\webserver\symed_images` pointing to target `\\DC\appserver\images`

the full-path of `webapi` in `DC` is `D:\webserver`

the full-path of the `app` in the `DC` is `D:\ProgramFiles\app`

Moreover, both `D:\ProgramFiles\app` & `D:\webserver` are shared folder on the network.

I created the symlinks logged in as an admin in the `DC`. Thinking that it would be easier, I used the [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#download) tool.

**The problem**

After creating the symlinks they work fine if one is logged in with admin rights to the `DC`. However if someone tries to access the symlink from the terminal services by navigating to the network share `DC\webserver\symed_images`, the user gets an error. Also, an error occurs if the web-browser is used.

**The question**

How do you make available a URL of a folder which is linked withing another folder via symlink, and make sure that all the users have access to that folder?

**Some stuff to consider**

Here I will write a couple of stuff which might be important to consider if you provide an answer: share permissions, security permissions of the shared folder, symlink creation, DFS namespaces.

---

**Solution Update 1:**

OK, after reading the suggested links and doing a little bit of research online it worked for me after creating a junction.

I used the following command: `mklink /J "D:\webserver\symed_images" "D:\ProgramFiles\app\images"`

Note that the directory which will act as junction (`symed_images`) in this case, should not be exist previously. It will be created automatically once the command is executed.

**Questions after Edit**

Now the junction works fine for those who try to access it via Windows Explorer, but when a web-browser is used, the webserver returns: `Server Error
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.`

What could be the problem in this case? How to make this link accessible via webbrowser?

Which security and sharing properties apply to the junction `"D:\webserver\symed_images`? The properties of the folder within which it is located `D:\webserver`? or the properties of the folder to which it targets `D:\ProgramFiles\app\images` ?

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to run other service on a domain controller.

Comment: Take a look at the answer referenced here: http://serverfault.com/questions/181228/following-windows-symlinks-in-network-shares?rq=1

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of your question: http://serverfault.com/questions/644578/enabling-a-symlink-in-terminal-server/644982